# $g(x)=\int_{0}^x f(t)dt$, Is $g$ bounded and monotone?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f$ be a continuous real valued function defined on $[0,1]$ such that $f(t)\geq 0$.

Let $$g(x)=\int_{0}^x f(t)dt$$

True/False: $g$ is bounded and monotone.

Efforts:

I considered taking the modulus

$|g(x)|\leq \int_{0}^x|f(t)|dt$

Now $f$ is continuous function on a compact interval, hence it is bounded. Therefore $g$ is also bounded.

For the monotone part, I used Leibniz Integral rule. Note that $g'(x)=f(x)$ and $f$ is positive. Therefore it follows that $g$ is monotone.

Am  I using the right ideas? I know I have to fill in the details.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes. You seem to be on the right track. For the second one though, Leibniz's rule is overkill. The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus suffices.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to take the absolute value. Since $g$ is continuous and since its domain is an interval which is closed and bounded, $g$ is bounded.

And if $x,y\in[0,1]$ with $x\leqslant y$, then
$$g(y)-g(x)=\int_0^yf(t)\,\mathrm dt-\int_0^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt=\int_x^yf(t)\,\mathrm dt\geqslant0.$$So, $g$ is increasing and therefore monotonic.